# How to display a PDF in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf, pdf-reader

How to read and display PDF in Objective-C?

Comment: you don't appear to have put any effort into asking your question...

Comment: Using a PDF parsing and rendering library, obviously.

Comment: Normal question I am asking also, whats up ?

Answer (score 26):

If you just want to display it, the easiest way is to load it in a UIWebView.

Comment: are you able to control the height of the UIWebView, Im having problems to get that fit my entire screen on an iPhone 5

Comment: Apple will stop accepting submissions of app updates that use UIWebView APIs starting from December 2020. You may see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more information.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to solely read and display PDFs to users, as the Mail app does on your iOS device with all the scrolling and zooming done for you, then I would use a UIDocumentInteractionController.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html

You'll find some useful code in one of my recent questions, here:

[UIDocumentInteractionController crashing upon exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152764/uidocumentinteractioncontroller-crashing-upon-exit)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

the easiset way is with the [UIDocumentInteractionController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIDocumentInteractionController)

Drawback: you need a local file-url