# How to convert the binary to pdf file on iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, swift, iphone, pdf, binary

I receive a binary pdf file, which is base64Binary encoded.
How can I convert it back on the iPhone? What tool kits can I use?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "convert it back"? Do you want to display it?

Comment: yes, I need to display back on the iPhone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved:

```
NSData theData = [NSData dataWithData:[GTMBase64 decodeString:theBinary]]; //first transfer it to NSData.

[m_oTestingWeb loadData:theData
               MIMEType:@"application/pdf"
       textEncodingName:@"UTF-8"
                baseURL:nil];                   //using the web view to show it back
```

Answer (score 4):

Solution

```
NSString *binaryString = [myDict objectForKey:@"key"];
NSData* myData = [NSData dataFromBase64String: binaryString];
NSLog(@" %@",datas);
[self savePDF:myData];
```

and save PDF is like this

```
- (void)savePDF:(NSData *)pdfContent
{
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask ,YES );
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

 NSString *finalPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPdf.pdf"];
 NSLog(@"%@",finalPath);
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalPath];
 [pdfContent writeToURL:url atomically:YES];

//    [aWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}
```

Get headers [here.](https://gist.github.com/1775589)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean NSData by the word "binary" then you can follow the following method.

I think if the binary data is already in PDF format then we can just use the normal `NSData` method to `writeToFile:atomically` to write it to the file.

```
[<NSDataObject> writeToFile:<FilePath> atomically:YES];
```

And then you can use the [DocInteraction](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html) to open and display a PDF File.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a binary (base64 pdf string) to pdf and show it you can do this for Swift 3:

```
// Here you convert the binary base 64 pdf string to pdf
let pdfData = Data(base64Encoded: theBase64PDFString, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)

// here you can display the pdf on a UIWebView
webView.load(pdfData!,
             mimeType: "application/pdf",
             textEncodingName: "UTF-8",
             baseURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

To display a PDF, you can simply [use a `UIWebView` and feed it the PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832245/iphone-can-we-open-pdf-file-using-uiwebview). If you want it a little more sophisticated, look at [Apple's ZoomingPDFViewer sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010281) (found that one in [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369568/how-to-display-a-pdf-in-objective-c/6369704#6369704)).

Comment: But I got the binary data, instead of the .pdf file on the website.

Comment: What do you mean with "binary data"?

Comment: Something like this:JVBERi0xLjQKJcfsj6IKNSAwIG9iago8PC9MZW5ndGggNiAwIFIvRmlsdGVyIC9GbGF0ZURlY29kZT4+CnN0cmVhbQp4nM1YS48cNRBWCJDQGyWB8A4PH7uR1riq/LwiEBK3RCNx2HAKJAHtBO3yW/i/fG73uN3LzGQYEWWzh9iecj2+r6ps94UymliZ/LcZPF133z4O6vlf3YUijm5ctOSUN6RT8sq5INqHIhjV9392j7KoC2EUdUYUJ4mKXaAql/bIGR+rHJndguS8mwVpi6CZBE0ryEVwDFI9/nEaXD7vLrqoJf8bF9rx07X6bpX3WujSwTqvVs86g/CTFRpFSAVAlpJTgZ1OntRq3fU3htUf3Q8rmCOV/2CF1O+dxKQtoLPJOk1RWXH4NcURz8vfumffNF7lXwsVjIAkFilstXNMrsRUjVQD4XgD4SAD7ngD7iADcrwBOcgAHW

Comment: This looks like it's Base64 encoded. See [Any base64 library on iphone-sdk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk) on how to decode it.

Answer (score 0):

Visit this site [base64 encoding](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BaseSixtyFour). Here You will get code for decoding base64 data to NSData. Using that data you can save pdf, view pdf using UIWebView or using Quartz Core.

Answer (score 0):

**To convert the binary into a PDF file**

```
@IBOutlet var pdfView: PDFView!

guard
    var fileURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last,
    let convertedData = Data(base64Encoded: data.base64EncodedData()) // data is the binary pdf 
    else {
    // handle error when getting documents URL
    return
}

fileURL.appendPathComponent("filename.pdf")

do {
    try convertedData.write(to: documentsURL)
} catch {
    // handle write error
}
```

***Bonus*: View the PDF without deprecated UIWebView API**

```
let pdfView = PDFView(frame: self.view.bounds)
self.view.addSubview(pdfView)
// Fit content in PDFView.
pdfView.autoScales = true
pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: fileURL)
```

Maybe it's a bit late, but I hope it will help someone else at least.