# How to display pdf files in slideshow?(iphone application development)

Tags: ios, iphone

In my project, I need to fetch some pdf files from server and display them in a slideshow.The slide show should contain the first page of each pdf or a preview image of each pdf and while clicking it, the particular pdf file should be open up. Is there any ios sdk available for implementing this functionality.

Comment: @Jacky Boy : Please share the link.

Comment: Have a look at this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369568/how-to-display-a-pdf-in-objective-c

Comment: @PhilippOtto : thanks... but what i need is slide show of pdf file

Comment: Use a UIPageViewController

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is nothing like that available in the iOS SDK. You will have to do it yourself. As mentioned in the Thread I posted in the comment, the [ZoomingPDFViewer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010281) Example of Apple is a good place to start learning how to show a pdf. If I understand you right, you won´t need the zooming stuff so you can leave it out. Then show your pdfs in a view controller with some gesture recognizers to give the user the possibility to switch between them and then a double click gesture recognizer to open it. And that is it.

Edit to Fogmeister´s comment: As he mentioned you can use the UIPageViewController to switch between the pdf thumbnails.

Answer (score 1):

For slide show you can use tableview or collection view and to view PDF check this 
https://github.com/vfr/Reader