# How to save and retrieve downloaded pdf files from skydrive in iphone application

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, pdf, onedrive

I am integrating sky drive in my iPhone application,I am trying to download pdf file from sky drive and I want to show that downloaded pdf file through application.Anyone knows about sky drive API's for iOS. 
How to save and show downloaded pdf file from sky drive.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  [Live SDK for iOS](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-iOS). For download files you can use `downloadFromPath:` method of `LiveConnectClient` class instance. [Live SDK developer guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243641) will help you. For choose way display pdf you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369568/how-to-display-a-pdf-in-objective-c) answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get a file from the web and store it locally, you can use NSData:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"http://www.somewhere.com/thefile.pdf";
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
if ( urlData )
{
  NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  

  NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"filename.pdf"];
  [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```